# How to insert case objects to mysql with alpakka slick connector

Tags: scala, akka, slick, alpakka

I'm writing some code to insert data into MySQL. I've decided to use Alpakka Slick Connector. Using that example: https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/latest/slick.html#using-a-slick-flow-or-sink I've successfully added data to DB, but it requires me to pass strings with SQL commands to Sink. Since I have collection of case objects I need to build commands from that objects. I can add methods to generate INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands to case classes but maybe there is some better way to add whole collection of objects without wrapping data with SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternative to using "plain SQL" is to use a "typed" insert. Here is an example using [`Slick.sink`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.14/slick/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/slick/scaladsl/Slick.scala#L88) that is adapted from [`SlickSpec`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.14/slick/src/test/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/slick/scaladsl/SlickSpec.scala):

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String)](tag, "USERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID")
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def * = (id, name)
}

val typedUsers = TableQuery[Users]

def insertUser(user: User): DBIO[Int] = typedUsers += user

val users = (1 to 40).map(i => User(i, s"Name$i")).toSet

Source(users)
  .runWith(Slick.sink(parallelism = 4, insertUser))
```

The above code inserts 40 users (using a collection of `User` case class instances) with a parallelism setting of four.